# Combine python dictionaries that share values and keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing some entity matching based on string edit distance and my results are a dictionary with keys (query string) and values [list of similar strings] based on some scoring criteria.

for example:

```
results = {
  'ben' : ['benj', 'benjamin', 'benyamin'],
  'benj': ['ben', 'beny', 'benjamin'],
  'benjamin': ['benyamin'],
  'benyamin': ['benjamin'],
  'carl': ['karl'],
  'karl': ['carl'],
}
```

Each value also has a corresponding dictionary item, for which it is the key (e.g. 'carl' and 'karl').

I need to combine the elements that have shared values. Choosing one value as the new key (lets say the longest string). In the above example I would hope to get:

```
results = {
  'benjamin': ['ben', 'benj', 'benyamin', 'beny', 'benjamin', 'benyamin'],
  'carl': ['carl','karl']
}
```

I have tried iterating through the dictionary using the keys, but I can't wrap my head around how to iterate and compare through each dictionary item and its list of values (or single value).

Comment: Should the lists be combined only when the values overlap, or should each value look for a matching key and then merge based on those values?  EDIT: I would guess the latter if I understand your example.

Comment: I should have said, each value will also be a key with its own dictionary item.

Comment: Slightly unrelated but you shouldn't mix strings and lists as your dict's values - even when you have a single string it should be contained in a list. This will make your code simpler and more robust by avoiding special cases.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Is the scoring criteria symmetric? If `similarity(a, b)` was the function which provides the scoring criteria, does `similarity(a, b)` return the same result as `similarity(b, a)`?

Comment: Yes the scoring is symmetric, the above example shows short strings for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one solution using `collections.defaultdict` and sets.

The desired output is very similar to what you have, and can be easily manipulated to align.

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = {
  'ben' : ['benj', 'benjamin', 'benyamin'],
  'benj': ['ben', 'beny', 'benjamin'],
  'benjamin': 'benyamin',
  'benyamin': 'benjamin',
  'carl': 'karl',
  'karl': 'carl',
}

d = defaultdict(set)

for i, (k, v) in enumerate(results.items()):
    w = {k} | (set(v) if isinstance(v, list) else {v})
    for m, n in d.items():
        if not n.isdisjoint(w):
            d[m].update(w)
            break
    else:
        d[i] = w

result = {max(v, key=len): v for k, v in d.items()}

# {'benjamin': {'ben', 'benj', 'benjamin', 'beny', 'benyamin'},
#  'carl': {'carl', 'karl'}}
```

Credit to @IMCoins for the idea of manipulating `v` to `w` in second loop.

**Explanation**

There are 3 main steps:

1. Convert values into a consistent set format, including keys and values from original dictionary.
2. Cycle through this dictionary and add values to a new dictionary. If there is an intersection with some key [i.e. sets are not disjoint], then use that key. Otherwise, add to new key determined via enumeration.
3. Create result dictionary in a final transformation by mapping max length key to values.

Comment: (1) whether you want keys in the resulting value? yes.  (2) which key to use if two or more values have same max length. Short of using a corpus of the most common names I don't know how you would priorities one or the other (open to suggestions or examples). Thank you.

Comment: OK, I've updated the solution to satisfy value containing key (not precisely your desired output for 'carl': 'karl').

Comment: Thanks jpp, i have run this on my actual data and it works. For my and others benefit please could you add some basic code comments.

Comment: @BenP I believe you might want to combine his answer and mine. His answer is in my opinion, losing unnecessary time computing a new dict with `set()`, while you could do it in the second loop just by changing `d[i] = v` by `d[i] = set(v)`

Comment: @IMCoins. I'm not sure I understand you. In my code `v` is already a `set`, so `v` and `set(v)` are equivalent, right? I upvote your answer, though, as it is performant.

Comment: I thought you could avoid the "useless" (to me) looping with your first one liner, and instead directly instantiate as `set()` in your second loop. But I didn't see the edge-cases on which  `n & v` is not possible between `set()` and `list()`. Nevermind.

Comment: @IMCoins, I understand now - included your improvement. I also use `isdisjoint` instead of `intersection` as this should perform better.

Comment: I was reviewing each answer as when using my actual data, jpp's answer results in 1600 results whereas IMCoins gives 1800 though I am yet to test with your improvements.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : Even though performance was not the question here, I took the liberty to perform some tests between jpp's answer, and mine... here is the full script. My script performs the tests in 17.79 seconds, and his in 23.5 seconds.

```
import timeit

results = {
  'ben' : ['benj', 'benjamin', 'benyamin'],
  'benj': ['ben', 'beny', 'benjamin'],
  'benjamin': ['benyamin'],
  'benyamin': ['benjamin'],
  'carl': ['karl'],
  'karl': ['carl'],
}

def imcoins(result):
    new_dict = {}
    # .items() for python3x
    for k, v in results.iteritems():
        flag = False
        #   Checking if key exists...
        if k not in new_dict.keys():
            #   But then, we also need to check its values.
            for item in v:
                if item in new_dict.keys():
                    #   If we update, set the flag to True, so we don't create a new value.
                    new_dict[item].update(v)
                    flag = True
            if flag == False:
                new_dict[k] = set(v)

    #   Now, to sort our newly created dict...
    sorted_dict = {}
    for k, v in new_dict.iteritems():
        max_string = max(v)
        if len(max_string) > len(k):
            sorted_dict[max(v, key=len)] = set(v)
        else:
            sorted_dict[k] =  v

    return sorted_dict

def jpp(result):
    from collections import defaultdict

    res = {i: {k} | (set(v) if isinstance(v, list) else {v}) \
          for i, (k, v) in enumerate(results.items())}

    d = defaultdict(set)

    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(res.items()):
        for m, n in d.items():
            if n & v:
                d[m].update(v)
                break
        else:
            d[i] = v

    result = {max(v, key=len): v for k, v in d.items()}
    return result

iterations = 1000000
time1 = timeit.timeit(stmt='imcoins(results)', setup='from __main__ import imcoins, results', number=iterations)
time2 = timeit.timeit(stmt='jpp(results)', setup='from __main__ import jpp, results', number=iterations)

print time1 # Outputs : 17.7903265883
print time2 # Outputs : 23.5605850732
```

If I move the import from his function to global scope, it gives...

imcoins : 13.4129249463 seconds

jpp : 21.8191823393 seconds